# How to write an Ltac to multiply both sides of a equation by a group element in Coq

Tags: coq, ltac

Using this definition of a group:

```
Structure group :=
  {
    G :> Set;

    id : G;
    op : G -> G -> G;
    inv : G -> G;

    op_assoc_def : forall (x y z : G), op x (op y z) = op (op x y) z;
    op_inv_l : forall (x : G), id = op (inv x) x;
    op_id_l : forall (x : G), x = op id x
  }.

(** Set implicit arguments *)
Arguments id {g}.
Arguments op {g} _ _.
Arguments inv {g} _.

Notation "x # y" := (op x y) (at level 50, left associativity).
```

And having proven this theorem:

```
Theorem mult_both_sides (G : group) : forall (a b c : G),
    a = b <-> c # a = c # b.
```

How do I write an Ltac that automates the process of left multiplying a given equality (either the goal itself or a hypothesis) by a given term?

Ideally, using this Ltac in a proof would look like this:

```
left_mult (arbitrary expression).
left_mult (arbitrary expression) in (hypothesis).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the [answer given by larsr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497702/377022), you can use `Tactic Notation`s to write

```
Tactic Notation "left_mult" uconstr(arbitrary_expression) :=
  apply (mult_both_sides _ _ _ arbitrary_expression).
Tactic Notation "left_mult" uconstr(arbitrary_expression) "in" hyp(hypothesis) :=
  apply (mult_both_sides _ _ _ arbitrary_expression) in hypothesis.
```

Using `uconstr` says "delay typechecking of this term until we plug it into `apply`".  (Other options include `constr` ("typecheck this at the call site") and `open_constr` ("typecheck this at the call site and fill in holes with evars").)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a specific tactic for this? If you just use `apply` to this

```
Goal forall (G:group) (a b c: G), a = b.
  intros.
  apply (mult_both_sides _ _ _ c).
```

Now your goal is

```
  G0 : group
  a, b, c : G0
  ============================
  c # a = c # b
```

If you want to modify a hypothesis `H`, then just do `apply ... in H`.

Comment: And declare `G`, `a` and `b` as implicit parameters, so that you do not need to type the 3 underscores.

Comment: That seems to do what I needed. However, I still would like to know how to make a tactic that uses the "in" keyword in the way that the "rewrite" or "apply" tactics do.